# CSS Grid auto-flow: dense; with data that is dynamically being loaded with Django

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a Django web app that is dynamically generating columns with a varied number of items within each column. I'm trying to get CSS' grid-auto-flow: dense; to fill in the gaps, but I can't get it to work.

Here is the HTML structure:

```
<div class="container" id="app">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div class="columns">
        {% for color, cards in cards_dict.items %}
            <div class="column">
                <h1>{{ color }}</h1>
                {% for card in cards %}
                    <div class="card">
                        {% if card in card_filter.qs %}
                            <p>{{ card.rating }}</p>{{ card.name }}
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS code I have so far:

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-template-rows: 50px 1fr 100px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

.columns {
    display: grid;
    background: mistyrose;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr));
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(150px, auto);
}

.column {
}

.card {
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
}
```

Here is what this currently generates:

[image: Image of current grid layout]

I'd like it for the columns to be right up to one another, with little/no space between. For example, in the image above, I'd like the Azorius column to be right beneath the 4.0 Tatyova, Benthic Druid card.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with Django. It is purely a css issue.

Comment: You're right. I removed the Django tag.

Comment: Thanks, you should have more luck with a response that way.